# OpenERP (View) - change look of selection field? (aka radio button)

Tags: python, view, field, selection, odoo

Is there a way to change how `selection` field looks? I need to change it to look like a bunch of boolean fields (technically it would be one field, not multiple boolean fields. Only look would change)?

It should look something like this (it looks like there are multiple fields, but technically it should be only one):

[image]

And it should function like selection field - that you can only select one value. Is it possible to do it?

**Update:**
Found this -  http://help.openerp.com/question/29061/how-to-add-radio-button-widget/

It seems it is possible to do with widget on OpenERP 8 (using radio widget for selection field). So I think it might be possible to move such functionality in OpenERP 7.

Comment: maybe there is a way to create a new widget for that, but unfortunately that is out of my league :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to move `radio` widget from OpenERP 8 to OpenERP 7. So I will post it how I've done. Maybe some one will need it too.

Basically you only need two main files, one `js` and one `xml` (also empty `__init__.py` is needed, because OpenERP will throw error that it didn't find that module).

in `__openerp__.py`:

```
 'js': ['static/src/js/widget_radio.js'],
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/widget_radio.xml'],
```

`widget_radio.js` (`web_widget_radio` is addon name):

```
openerp.web_widget_radio = function (instance)
{
    instance.web.form.widgets.add('radio', 'instance.web_widget_radio.FieldRadio');
    instance.web_widget_radio.FieldRadio = instance.web.form.AbstractField.extend(instance.web.form.ReinitializeFieldMixin, {
        template: 'FieldRadio',
        events: {
            'click input': 'click_change_value'
        },
        init: function(field_manager, node) {
            /* Radio button widget: Attributes options:
            * - "horizontal" to display in column
            * - "no_radiolabel" don't display text values
            */
            this._super(field_manager, node);
            this.selection = _.clone(this.field.selection) || [];
            this.domain = false;
        },
        initialize_content: function () {
            this.uniqueId = _.uniqueId("radio");
            this.on("change:effective_readonly", this, this.render_value);
            this.field_manager.on("view_content_has_changed", this, this.get_selection);
            this.get_selection();
        },
        click_change_value: function (event) {
            var val = $(event.target).val();
            val = this.field.type == "selection" ? val : +val;
            if (val == this.get_value()) {
                this.set_value(false);
            } else {
                this.set_value(val);
            }
        },
        /** Get the selection and render it
         *  selection: [[identifier, value_to_display], ...]
         *  For selection fields: this is directly given by this.field.selection
         *  For many2one fields:  perform a search on the relation of the many2one field
         */
        get_selection: function() {
            var self = this;
            var selection = [];
            var def = $.Deferred();
            if (self.field.type == "many2one") {
                var domain = instance.web.pyeval.eval('domain', this.build_domain()) || [];
                if (! _.isEqual(self.domain, domain)) {
                    self.domain = domain;
                    var ds = new instance.web.DataSetStatic(self, self.field.relation, self.build_context());
                    ds.call('search', [self.domain])
                        .then(function (records) {
                            ds.name_get(records).then(function (records) {
                                selection = records;
                                def.resolve();
                            });
                        });
                } else {
                    selection = self.selection;
                    def.resolve();
                }
            }
            else if (self.field.type == "selection") {
                selection = self.field.selection || [];
                def.resolve();
            }
            return def.then(function () {
                if (! _.isEqual(selection, self.selection)) {
                    self.selection = _.clone(selection);
                    self.renderElement();
                    self.render_value();
                }
            });
        },
        set_value: function (value_) {
            if (value_) {
                if (this.field.type == "selection") {
                    value_ = _.find(this.field.selection, function (sel) { return sel[0] == value_;});
                }
                else if (!this.selection.length) {
                    this.selection = [value_];
                }
            }
            this._super(value_);
        },
        get_value: function () {
            var value = this.get('value');
            return value instanceof Array ? value[0] : value;
        },
        render_value: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.toggleClass("oe_readonly", this.get('effective_readonly'));
            this.$("input:checked").prop("checked", false);
            if (this.get_value()) {
                this.$("input").filter(function () {return this.value == self.get_value();}).prop("checked", true);
                this.$(".oe_radio_readonly").text(this.get('value') ? this.get('value')[1] : "");
            }
        }
    });
};
```

`widget_radio.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="FieldRadio">
        <span t-attf-class="oe_form_field oe_form_field_radio #{widget.options.horizontal ? 'oe_horizontal' : 'oe_vertical'}" t-att-style="widget.node.attrs.style">
            <span t-if="!widget.get('effective_readonly')">
                <t t-if="widget.options.horizontal">
                    <t t-set="width" t-value="Math.floor(100 / widget.selection.length)"/>
                    <t t-if="!widget.options.no_radiolabel">
                        <t t-foreach="widget.selection" t-as="selection">
                            <label t-att-for="widget.uniqueId + '_' + selection[0]" t-att-style="'width: ' + width + '%;'"><t t-esc="selection[1]"/></label>
                        </t>
                        <br/>
                    </t>
                    <t t-foreach="widget.selection" t-as="selection">
                        <div t-att-style="'width: ' + width + '%;'">
                            <span class="oe_radio_input"><input type="radio" t-att-name="widget.uniqueId" t-att-id="widget.uniqueId + '_' + selection[0]" t-att-value="selection[0]"/></span>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
                <t t-if="!widget.options.horizontal">
                    <t t-foreach="widget.selection" t-as="selection">
                        <div>
                            <span class="oe_radio_input"><input type="radio" t-att-id="widget.uniqueId + '_' + selection[0]" t-att-name="widget.uniqueId" t-att-value="selection[0]"/></span><label t-if="!widget.options.no_radiolabel" t-att-for="widget.uniqueId + '_' + selection[0]"><t t-esc="selection[1]"/></label>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </span>
            <span t-if="widget.get('effective_readonly')" class="oe_radio_readonly"><t t-esc="widget.get('value')[1]"/></span>
        </span>
    </t>
</templates>
```

**P.S.** You can find original code in OpenERP trunk version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its possible. You can see a similar example in openerp itself. Go to `settings / users /access rights tab`. There you can see all the  list of boolean and selection fields for adding the groups. Actually it is a many2many field related to res.groups and its view is modified in such a way that all the groups that are inherited and under the same category will be viewed as a selection list and all others will be in boolean. Please check the code in the `base/ res/res_users.py` file. Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: That example looks quite similar to what I need. I jut don't understand how it is done. In access rights it shows in view as normal selection if there are not more than 3 groups to choose from. If there are more, then in view those groups start looking like boolean values. But I don't see where it is done in code to work like that? In view I only see `groups_id` used without any widget or anything and in `res_users.py` don't see where it is done to give that functionality.

Comment: Its done from the python side. in that example selection list comes when a group inherit other group. for example consider the group category sale. here the group see own leads is inherited by see all leads and see all leads is inherited by manager.if we select manager. then by default, see own leads and see all leads group will be available for the user.thats why it is showing in selection list.all others in boolean

Comment: A key component to radio buttons is that only one button from a group can be selected.  The user permissions screen does not function like that.